# Azure API Management (consumption tier): First request gives timeout and is not sent to backend service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a service running behind an Azure API Management instance running in the consumption tier.  When no traffic has been sent to the API Management instance in a while (15 minutes isn't enough to trigger it, but an hour is), the first request sent takes about 3 minutes 50 seconds and returns a HTTP 500 with this body content:

```
<html><head><title>500 - The request timed out.</title></head><body>  <font color ="#aa0000">         <h2>500 - The request timed out.</h2></font>  The web server failed to respond within the specified time.</body></html>
```

Following requests work fine.  Based on application logs and testing with an API Management instance pointing to my local machine via ngrok, it doesn't look like API management is even trying to connect to the backend for these requests.  For the local test, I ran my app under the debugger, put a breakpoint in my service method (there's no auth that could get in the way) and watched the "output" window in Visual Studio.  It never hit my breakpoint, and never showed anything in the output window for that "500 request timed out" request.  When I made another request to API Management, it forwarded along to my service as expected, giving me output and hitting my breakpoint.

Is this some known issue with API Management consumption tier that I need to find some way to work around (ie. a service regularly pinging it)?  Or a possible configuration issue with the way I've set up my API Management instance?

My API management instance is deployed via an ARM template using the consumption tier in North Central US and has some REST and some SOAP endpoints (this request I've been using for testing is one of the SOAP ones and uses the envelope header to specify the SOAP action).

Additional information:

- The request is question is about 2KB, and a response from the server (which doesn't play into this scenario as the call never makes it to my server) is about 1KB, so it's not an issue with request/response sizes.
- When I turn on request tracing (by sending the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key + Ocp-Apim-Trace headers), this 500 response I'm getting doesn't have the Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location header with the trace info that other requests do.
- I get this behavior when I send 2 requests (to get the 4-minute 500 response and then a normal 5s 200 response), wait an hour, and make another request (which gets the 4-minute delay and 500 response), so I don't believe this could be related to the instance serving too much traffic (at least too much of my traffic).
- Further testing shows that this happens about once every 60 to 90 minutes, even if I send one request every minute trying to keep the APIM instance "alive".

Comment: Did you find out what was causing the issue? I'm finding similar issues where the first request always fails, then the second (identical) request will always succeed a second later.

Comment: @SamBarber - no, we weren't able to find a solution on consumption tier.  We ended up switching our production and final testing environment off of consumption (the others worked fine) and just living with the "startup" delay on the lower environments.

Comment: Ok thanks @Jonathan Rupp.

Comment: This could be completely unrelated to your issue, however my issue was that during a coldstart API Management adds an extra header: x-ms-coldstart:1. Because I was using Shared Key Lite Authorization on Queue Storage on my backend (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) this extra header was breaking the first attempt. Deleting the header on the backend request fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. (possibly due to large payload). There is no issue at APIM level. Analyze the APIM inspector trace and you should see HTTP 500 status code under 'forward-request' response attribute.

You need to understand who is throwing these HTTP 404 and 500 responses, APIM, or the backend SOAP API. The best way to get that answer is to collect APIM inspector trace to inspect request and response. [Debug your APIs using request tracing](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector)

The Consumption tier exposes serverless properties. It runs on a shared infrastructure, can scale down to zero in times of no traffic and is billed per execution. Connections are pooled and reused unless explicitly closed by the back end. [Api management service limits](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/api-management-service-limits.md)

**1.** These pattern of symptoms are also often known to occurs due to
network address translation (SNAT) port limits with your APIM
service.

Whenever a client calls one of your APIM APIs, Azure API Management service opens a SNAT port to access your backend API. Azure uses SNAT and a Load Balancer (not exposed to customers) to communicate with end points outside Azure in the public IP address space, as well as end points internal to Azure that aren't using Virtual Network service endpoints. (This situation is only applicable to backend APIs exposed on public IPs.)

Each instance of API Management service is initially given a pre-allocated number of SNAT ports. That limit affects opening connections to the same host and port combination. SNAT ports are used up when you have repeated calls to the same address and port combination. Once a SNAT port has been released, the port is available for reuse as needed. The Azure Network load balancer reclaims SNAT ports from closed connections only after waiting four minutes.

A rapid succession of client requests to your APIs may exhaust the pre-allocated quota of SNAT ports if these ports are not closed and recycled fast enough, preventing your APIM service from processing client requests in a timely manner.

> Following strategies can be considered:
>
> - Use multiple IPs for your backend URLs
> - Place your APIM and backend service in the same VNet
> - Place your APIM in a virtual network and route outbound calls to    Azure Firewall
> - Consider response caching and other backend performance tuning    (configuring certain APIs with response caching to reduce latency
>   between client applications calling your API and your APIM backend
>   load.)
> - Consider implementing access restriction policies (policy can be used    to prevent API usage spikes on a per key basis by limiting the
>   call    rate per a specified time period.)

**2.** The forward-request policy forwards the incoming request to the
backend service specified in the request context. The backend
service URL is specified in the API settings and can be changed
using the set backend service policy.

**Policy statement:**

```
<forward-request timeout="time in seconds" follow-redirects="false | true" buffer-request-body="false | true" buffer-response="true | false" fail-on-error-status-code="false | true"/>
```

**Example**:
The following API level policy forwards all API requests to the backend service with a timeout interval of 60 seconds.

```
<!-- api level -->
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base/>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request timeout="60"/>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base/>
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

> Attribute:    timeout="integer"
>
> Description: The amount of time in seconds to wait for the HTTP
> response headers to be returned by the backend service before a
> timeout error is raised. Minimum value is 0 seconds. Values greater
> than 240 seconds may not be honored as the underlying network
> infrastructure can drop idle connections after this time.
>
> Required: No
>
> Default: None
>
> This policy can be used in the following policy sections and scopes.
>
> - Policy sections: backend
> - Policy scopes: all scopes

Checkout similar [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/15165687-expose-a-way-to-modify-the-apim-idle-timeout-or-tc) for your reference. Also, [refer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/troubleshooting-4xx-and-5xx-errors-with-azure-apim-services/ba-p/2115744) for detailed troubleshooting of 5oo error for APIM.

Comment: I hadn't seen that last link before - I'll drill into some of the thinks listed there, since it references a kind of logs I haven't seen before (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/troubleshooting-4xx-and-5xx-errors-with-azure-apim-services/ba-p/2115744).